# Append strings on click jquery with delimiter

Tags: javascript, jquery, concatenation

I have two text boxes with each having a button. On click of the button the strings have to be appended. Say I clicked the first button it will save in a string and I click on the second button the second string should be appended to the first one.

```
<input type="text" id="name_1"> <input type="button" id="button_1" value="add">
<input type="text" id="name_2"> <input type="button" id="button_2" value="add">

    <br>
<input type="submit">

$('[id^="button_"]').on("click", function() {
    name = $('#name_'+$(this).attr('id').split('_')[1]).val();
    alert(name);
});
```

partial working demo here: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/M7S53/)

example: john_david where john is the first string and david is the second string

Comment: i can not see `value attribute` for `input`..are you tring to access value when user write in it.??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you are looking for this :-

```
$('[id^="button_"]').on("click", function() {
    var name = "";
    $('[id^="button_"]').each(function(){
        name = name+$('#name_'+$(this).attr('id').split('_')[1]).val();
    });
    alert(name);
});
```

See [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/M7S53/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `name` variable as `global` and when `click` happens `append` string to that variable.

**<kbd>[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/M7S53/4/)</kbd>**

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
var name = "";
$('[id^="button_"]').on("click", function() {
    if(name == ""){ name = name+$(this).prev("input").val(); }
    else{ name = name+"_"+$(this).prev("input").val(); }
    alert(name);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('[id^="button_"]').on("click", function() {
  name = $('#name_'+$(this).attr('id').split('_')[1]).val();
  alert(name);
});
$('[type="submit"]').on("click", function() {
  name = $('#name_1').val() + $('#name_2').val();
  alert(name);
});
```